# Error Running Phoenix on EMR From Spark using yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I am trying to run a simple Phoenix program that is working fine in local mode using spark-submit.  But getting following exception running in cluster mode.

> l.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getQueryPlan(PhoenixInputFormat.java:201)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getSplits(PhoenixInputFormat.java:87)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.doSaveToEs(EsSpark.scala:94)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:79)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:76)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveJsonToEs(EsSpark.scala:111)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark$.saveJsonToEs(JavaEsSpark.scala:63)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(JavaEsSpark.scala)
>       at com.voicebase.etl.PhoenixToElasticSearch.main(PhoenixToElasticSearch.java:99)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:72)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:124)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:224)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:98)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getInputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:57)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getQueryPlan(PhoenixInputFormat.java:176)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
>       ... 33 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:134)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrlParser.(ConnectionUrlParser.java:124)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:113)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:192)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:194)
>       ... 32 more
>   18/05/08 13:05:03 ERROR mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat: Failed to get the query plan with error [Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getQueryPlan(PhoenixInputFormat.java:201)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getSplits(PhoenixInputFormat.java:87)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>       at com.voicebase.etl.PhoenixToElasticSearch.main(PhoenixToElasticSearch.java:104)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:72)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:124)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:224)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:98)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getInputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:57)
>       at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getQueryPlan(PhoenixInputFormat.java:176)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
>       ... 31 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:134)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrlParser.(ConnectionUrlParser.java:124)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:113)
>       at com.mysql.cj.core.conf.url.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:192)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:194)
>       ... 30 more
>   18/05/08 13:05:03 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
>   18/05/08 13:05:03 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@1a28be00{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
>   18/05/08 13:05:03 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.16.129.152:4040
>   18/05/08 13:05:03 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
>   18/05/08 13:05:03 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors